# IE8 - Object doesn't support this property or method (window.frames[i];)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

first time posting.

I have an intermittent issue with IE8 where I get an:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

This occurs when retrieving an iFrame into a variable using the following:

```
var wfw = window.frames[i];
```

The bit that is confusing me is that previous to this line of code I call:

```
var length = window.frames.length;
```

which returns the value 4. I guess my question is why can I not retrieve something that exists?

```
var length = window.frames.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    // Grab the window.frames collection so that we can iterate through it.
    var wfw = window.frames[i];
    try {
        // Attempt to push the BISCheckEvent code onto the child Window and execute it. This is to account for Iframes that have already loaded
        wfw.eval("var BISCheckEvent = new " + BISCheckEventImpl.toString() + "; BISCheckEvent.attachHandler(); ");
    } catch(e){
        // Iframe has no source, so just capture the exception and move on.
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's an "intermittent issue", then it's likely caused by something other than the simple access using `i`.

Comment: Seems to me like `window.frames` is sometimes `undefined`. Perhaps set a breakpoint on your `var wfw` line and inspect it, or just throw it into an `alert` (or `console`, forgot if IE8 supports that), to check? I tried `window.frames` and `.length` and `[0]` in an IE8 VM I have, and all of them worked.

Comment: I don't have IE8 in front of me, so I can't test this, but have you tried `window.frames(i)` instead? Parens instead of brackets. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537459(VS.85).aspx). If that's not it, are you SURE it's the `window.frames[i]` bit that's throwing an error?

Comment: Make sure all frames are already loaded in the parent page.

Comment: I already had the same problem as you, one of my frames had was pointing nowhere (src=""). IE8 did not like it, so instead of having src="", i created a blank htm file called blank.htm and change my frame src to this file. It suddenly works... why? I dont know unfortunately.

Comment: Cheers for your replies. I have caught the loop with a breakpoint and attempted to check the frames in the console. Something is being set:
>>window.frames[3]
  Object doesn't support this property or method
>>window.frames[4]
undefined

Comment: `window.frames[4] undefined` not available at this moment.

Comment: @beercodebeer Thanks, but unfortunately this has resulted in a 
>>window.frames(0)
  Unspecified error.

Comment: @Sheikh Heera thanks for your suggestion. I'll take a look tomorrow morning. I'm signing off for now.

Comment: Try to loop `onload`, like `window.onload = function(){ //code }`

Comment: Try to rename `var length = window.frames.length;` to `var xLength = window.frames.length;` and go with that. IE is **VERY** picky on variable names !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the late reply on this one however Sheikh Heera's suggestion of "Making sure all the frames loaded in the parent page" has addressed this issue.